# Como pausar o youtube-player via typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Angular (9.11) e preciso saber quanto tempo o usuário assistiu a um vídeo no youtube. Eu estou usando o componente youtube-player do angular. Eu monitoro no próprio componente a mudança de estado. Meu problema é quando o usuário sai da página sem ter pausado o vídeo, pois não é disparado o evento de mudança de estado. Como posso obter no **ngOnDestroy** o tempo do vídeo ou enviar um comando para o vídeo pausar?

```
<div class="col-12 text-center p-3">
  <youtube-player
    id="player"
    videoId="{{content?.content}}"
    (stateChange)="playerEvent($event)"
    width="712px"
    height="400px"
  ></youtube-player>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o truque, salvar o event que é disparado quando o vídeo fica *ready* para tocar:

```
 <youtube-player
    videoId="{{content?.content}}"
    (stateChange)="playerEvent($event)"
    (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
    width="712px"
    height="400px"
  ></youtube-player>
```

E no typescript:

```
savePlayer(event) {
    this.player = event;
}
```

A variável *this.player* terá tudo que você precisa para comandar o vídeo por script.